# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception saying that array is smaller than it actually is

Tags: java, arrays

My program is comparing two strings inside two for loops. Upon running, it produces the error:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`, even though the arrays are initialized for enough space. The line of code is:

```
if(keywords[a].equals(tokenizedString[b])&&tokenizedString[a].equals("1"))
```

Where `keywords` is initialized:

```
String[] keywords={"0","add","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

Where `tokenizedString` is initialized:

```
String[] tokenizedString={"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

Why, when I run it, is it saying that two is out of bounds when the only two arrays being used in that statement are obviously bigger?

The relevant part of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int KEYWORDS = 3;
        String[] keywords =
                        {"0", "add", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] tokenizedString =
                        {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
        int stringCounter = 1;
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
        String answer = null;
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            answer = (String) st.nextElement();
            System.out.println(answer);
            tokenizedString[stringCounter] = answer;
            stringCounter++;
        }
        String[] functions;
        functions = new String[10];
        functions = testForKeywords(tokenizedString, keywords, stringCounter, KEYWORDS);
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        String[] numberss = {"1", "2"};
        numbers = testForNumbers(tokenizedString, numberss, stringCounter, 2);
    }

    public static int[] testForNumbers(String[] tokenizedString, String[] keywords, int inputs,
                    int numbKeywords) {
        int[] functions = new int[inputs + 1];
        int funCounter = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a <= numbKeywords; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b <= inputs; b++) {
                if (keywords[a].equals(tokenizedString[b]) && tokenizedString[a].equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("Yay");
                    functions[funCounter] = 1;
                    funCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return functions;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler isn't saying anything. That is an exception thrown at run time. Show us a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: Please give a *minimal working example* that reproduces the exception (perhaps the arrays are for instance set to something different during the process).

Comment: Since there is not enough code here to solve the riddle, I just guess: You either assign a new array reference to one of your variables, or you're initializing local variables with the above lines, instead of the correct fields (shadowing).

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? Often this yields plenty of information - you can place a watch for the given arrays f.e. or evaluate the expression right before you actually execute them.

Comment: It's highly probable the problem is the uncalled for `=` signs in both `for (int a=0;a<=numbKeywords;a++)` and `for (int b=0;b<=inputs;b++)`

Comment: Those or less than or equal to signs, no?

Comment: @APCoding, To solve those kinds of errors, you should print out `a` and `b` before any use of such kind: `SOME-ARRAY[a]`, and also print in general the length of the array they are working on, and you will find you're problem in no time.

Comment: It is very obvious: `keywords[a]` This is your problem. `a` can be **2**, but the last index of `numberss` (which as passed to a method for argument `keywords`) is **1**.

Comment: What is `testForKeywords(...)`?

Comment: as @Tom already stated, `keywords[a]` produces the OOBE - in your outer for loop you specified `int a = 0; a <= numbKeywords; a++` where numberKeywords is set to 2 and the keywords-array contains only 2 entries `1` and `2` (but it starts at index 0!) - if you change the check in the outer-loop to `a < numbKeywords` chances are high the exception should be gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused as to the value of `keywords` at the point the error occurs.

Your error occurs in `testForNumbers()` where you have a local (method scope) variable `keywords` passed in as an argument.  If you look where you call this, you pass in `numberss` in this position.

`numberss` has only two members - so has indexes `0` and `1` only - trying to access index `2` will indeed throw this Exception at runtime